# Fix footer in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with a footer for a website I am developing. There is an active carousel on the homepage. The footer moves slightly up leaving space below it at certain times. Could this contribute to the footer? I would like to have the footer in a stationary/fixed position. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Here is the HTML markup below:

```html
<footer class="bg-info">
        
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><img src="images/Heart_n_hands.png" class="float-left" alt="logo" style="width:100px;">
            <span class="font-weight-bold">Our Neighbor Association</span> <br>
              <span>&copy; Copyright 2018</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
             <address class="font-weight-bold">1200 W Smithfeld Avenue Somewhereville, MI 48326 <br> (888)-555-1234</address>
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
              <span class="font-weight-bold">Sign up for Updates!</span>
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-control bg-light">
                <label><small class="font-weight-bold">E-Mail:
                <input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail" autocomplete="email" placeholder="Enter you E-Mail!" pattern="" required>
                </small></label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </footer>
```

Comment: what css you are using for footer ?

Comment: Check this [bootstrap 4 sticky footer template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

Answer (score 3):

Use d-flex from Bootstrap 4, here is my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html>
    <style>
        html,body{
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <body class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="flex-fill">
        (main div) i fill the black space
        </div>
        <footer class="mt-auto bg-info">Footer always down,at any height</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

First, the body and html fill the page with 100% height.
Then, "d-flex flex-column" class body will arrange all element inside in vertical direction.
Use "mt-auto" to make footer stay on bottom.
Last make your main container "flex-fill" so the container will fill up the empty space.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post problems in the answers section but rather create a new question which will have more visibility and be more likely to find and answer.

Comment: This code solve it! please try it on code snippet, and mark if it solve your problem too. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The provided solution for a sticky footer in Bootstrap 4 is [sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/):

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px;
  /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  /* Not required */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<main role="main" class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer</h1>
  <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>
  <p>Use <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar">the sticky footer with a fixed navbar</a> if need be, too.</p>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

If you want a solution which keeps the footer down when page is short but lets it stay below longer pages (not fixed), you could use flexbox. It also has the **huge** advantage footer doesn't need to have a fixed height here:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<main role="main" class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer</h1>
  <p class="lead">This one has the advantage you don't need to set a fixed height for footer (which would need to be the <code>&lt;body></code>'s bottom margin).</p>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `navbar navbar-fixed-bottom` class in **footer** tag.

```
<footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom bg-info">
     content...
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

for fix footer, must use this code in HTML and CSS codes

```css
body,html{
   height:100%;
}

.main{
height:auto;
min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<h1>your contents here</h1>
</div>




<footer class="bg-info">
        
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div><img src="images/Heart_n_hands.png" class="float-left" alt="logo" style="width:100px;">
            <span class="font-weight-bold">Our Neighbor Association</span> <br>
              <span>&copy; Copyright 2018</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
             <address class="font-weight-bold">1200 W Smithfeld Avenue Somewhereville, MI 48326 <br> (888)-555-1234</address>
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
              <span class="font-weight-bold">Sign up for Updates!</span>
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-control bg-light">
                <label><small class="font-weight-bold">E-Mail:
                <input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail" autocomplete="email" placeholder="Enter you E-Mail!" pattern="" required>
                </small></label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </footer>
```

You must have two parts: 1: main, 2: footer 
The footer should not be inside main